# perl: How to make 'warn' think we read from a file?

Tags: perl

I have a function (a variation of string`++`):

```
sub inc
{
  $_[0] =~ /^(.*?)([0-9]+)$/;
  my ($a,$b)=($1,$2);
  die "cannot increment [$_[0]]" unless defined $b;
  warn "increment overflow [$_[0]]" if length(++$b) != length($2);
  $a.$b;
}
```

It is invoked in many places of a script, on different data (sometimes from a file, sometimes from a database).

When I read from a filehandle, `die` and `warn` print a message like this:

```
cannot increment [abc] at script line 5, <filehandle> line 123.
```

otherwise a shorter message is printed:

```
cannot increment [abc] at script line 5.
```

When I read from database I would like to have a message like this:

```
cannot increment [abc] at script line 5, <SELECT...> line 123.
```

Is it possible?

Setting the line number is quite simple: an assignment to `$.` can be made. But how to set the 'filehandle' part and make it visible?

I have found such a workaround:

```
my $fh = "SELECT...";
open $fh, "/dev/null";
<$fh>;
```

but it is a bit long, and it actually does open a file.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  This feels like an XY Problem, so it would help if you gave more setup.  Perhaps the [SIG handlers DIE and WARN](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) are relevant to your question, but can't really say without more explanation.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have something—perhaps an IDE—that needs to parse Perl error messages, and you don't know how to make it work when it sometimes doesn't have a data input line number? There are much better ways to do this if you explain the situation properly

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot because I am reading from a database (but parsing some other computed structure could also be the case) and I wanted to have longer messages. It is easy to set `$.` to have correct "line" number in the message, though.

Comment: I have updated the question to include more context.

Comment: "I wanted to have longer messages" --> Well, then just add some random strings to it. Like so: `warn "increment overflow ... " . "random junk text xyxyxyxyxyxy"`.

Comment: @TLP OK, but it should depend on the context of invoking the function: if there is a file opened, a database query, which line was read last, etc.

Comment: @mik If there is an active file handle, it will be added. If you want to be explicit about what data to add to the warning, then be specific and add it.

Comment: So you really want more complete error reporting? Or do you need it to be custom in some particular way to the separate sources that you mention? For example, what is it that you need that is not provided by the answer by [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](http://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) ?

Comment: @zdim I want a more complete error reporting without changing the places where error reporting is done :)

Answer (score 1):

The filehandle information that appears in `warn` and `die` messages is only set after calls to `<HANDLE>`, `readline`, `tell`, `eof`, and `seek`. When you fetch data from a database with DBI, for example, you're not calling any of these, so you have to pass the extra data yourself.

One way to do this is to write a custom exception class that stringifies to the text you want:

```
package MyException;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.18.0;

use overload '""' => \&as_string;

sub new {
    my ($self, $message, $src, $src_line) = @_;
    my ($package, $file, $line) = caller;

    if (! defined $src && ref ${^LAST_FH} eq 'GLOB') {
        $src = *${^LAST_FH}{NAME};
        $src_line = $.;
    }

    bless { message  => $message,
            file     => $file,
            line     => $line,
            src      => $src,
            src_line => $src_line }, $self;
}

sub as_string {
    my ($self) = @_;

    my $message = "$self->{message} at $self->{file} line $self->{line}";

    if (defined $self->{src} && defined $self->{src_line}) {
        $message .= ", <$self->{src}> line $self->{src_line}";
    }

    $message .= "\n";
}

1;
```

Note that Perl 5.18.0 or up is required to use the read-only [`${^LAST_FH}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7B%5ELAST_FH%7D) variable, which holds a reference to the last read filehandle.

---

Here's how you would use this when reading from a file:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use MyException;

while (<DATA>) {
    warn MyException->new('foo'); # equivalent to warn 'foo'
}

__DATA__
first
second
```

Output:

```
foo at ./myscript line 9, <DATA> line 1
foo at ./myscript line 9, <DATA> line 2
```

---

And here's how you would use it when fetching records from a database:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use DBI;
use MyException;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:test', 'user', 'pass', {
    RaiseError => 1
});

my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM test';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;

my $count;
while (my $row = $sth->fetch) {
    warn MyException->new('foo', $sql, ++$count);
}
```

Output:

```
foo at ./myscript line 19, <SELECT * FROM test> line 1
foo at ./myscript line 19, <SELECT * FROM test> line 2
```

(Unfortunately, DBI doesn't provide a method to get the number of rows that have been fetched so far, so you have to count them yourself.)

---

Since you're trying to `warn` or `die` from inside a subroutine, you have to do a little bit more work. The simplest approach for `die` would be to trap exceptions from your subroutine with `eval` and re-throw them:

```
my $count = 1;
while (my $row = $sth->fetch) {
    eval {
        inc($row[0]);
    };

    if ($@ =~ /^(cannot increment \[.*?\])/) {
        die MyException->new($1, $sql, $count);
    }
    elsif ($@) {
        die $@;
    }

    $count++;
}
```

You can handle warnings in a similar way by creating a `__WARN__` handler:

```
{
    my $count = 1;

    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
        if ($_[0] =~ /^(increment overflow \[.*?\])/) {
            warn MyException->new($1, $sql, $count);
        }
        else {
            warn @_;
        }
    };

    while (my $row = $sth->fetch) {
        inc($row[0]);
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This exception handling implementation should be extremely useful for many.

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer this implementation of your `inc` subroutine. Your own uses the reserved variables `$a` and `$b`, as well as saving and retrieving the initial non-numeric part of the string

Note that the STDERR output is not in sync with STDOUT, so the warning appears prematurely in the aggregated text. In reality the warning is issued only when the passed string has an all-nines numeric field

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $s = 'ZZ90';

for ( 1 .. 20 ) {
    $s = inc_str($s);
    print $s, "\n";
}

sub inc_str {

    my ($str) = @_;

    $str =~ s{([0-9]+)$}{
        my $num = $1;
        warn "Increment overflow [$str]"  unless $num =~ /[^9]/;
        sprintf '%0*d', length($num), $num+1;
    }e or die "Cannot increment [$str]";

    return $str;
}
```

#### output

```
Increment overflow [ZZ99] at E:\Perl\source\inc_str.pl line 18.
ZZ91
ZZ92
ZZ93
ZZ94
ZZ95
ZZ96
ZZ97
ZZ98
ZZ99
ZZ100
ZZ101
ZZ102
ZZ103
ZZ104
ZZ105
ZZ106
ZZ107
ZZ108
ZZ109
ZZ110
```

Comment: This is helpful, but did not answer my question, which was about `warn` and `die` messages.